# Solving $g(x)=\int_{3}^{x} g(t) dt$

Tags: integral-equations

The question is what set of continuous functions solves the problem $g(x)=\int_{3}^{x} g(t) dt$.
My answer so far:
g(3)=0, g'(x)=g(x)-g(3) therefore g(x)=g'(x)=$ce^x$.
Obviously $ce^x=ce^x-ce^3$ doesn't really work out.
Where's my mistake? And what's the correct answer?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the derivative we find
$$g'(x)=g(x)$$
hence
$$g(x)=\lambda e^x$$
and since $g(3)=0$ then $\lambda=0$ hence $g=0$.